# How to Rename Column SQL Server with []

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lLLe.png)

I entered the wrong column name and included [] as shown above [avail_memory_mb], I want to remove [] using the syntax, how do I do that?

I have tried using syntax
`EXEC sp_RENAME '[db_isdv_itsm].[dbo].[tbl_m_comp_sysboot_time].[avail_memory_mb]', 'avail_memory', 'COLUMN'`

but an error appears

`Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_RENAME, Line 247 Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.`

Comment: try escaping the column `[]` by using `[[]]` instead, like: `EXEC sp_RENAME '[db_isdv_itsm].[dbo].[tbl_m_comp_sysboot_time].[[avail_memory_mb]]', 'avail_memory', 'COLUMN'`

Comment: error Msg 15253, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_RENAME, Line 111
Syntax error parsing SQL identifier '[db_isdv_itsm].[dbo].[tbl_m_comp_sysboot_time].[[avail_memory_mb]]'.

Comment: `sp_rename` doesn't allow four part naming. You need to connect to the relevant database.

Comment: Do you really use SQL Server 2008 R2? That's a 13 year old version, by now fully unsupported. Still, SSMS should still be able to connect to it. Using the GUI will allow you to fix the name without having to write the actual SQL, *and* avoid similar errors in the future. SSMS can generate the SQL script for each operation too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method, in this case, would be to use a different delimit identifier to brackets (`[]`) for your column's name:

```sql
EXEC sys.sp_rename N'dbo.tbl_m_comp_sysboot_time."[avail_memory_mb]"', N'avail_memory', N'COLUMN';
```

If you "must" use brackets, then you need to escape the right bracket (`]`):

```sql
EXEC sys.sp_rename N'dbo.tbl_m_comp_sysboot_time.[[avail_memory_mb]]]', N'avail_memory', N'COLUMN';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VeYdb2bF)

Note that I also removed the database name in both examples. This is because `sys.sp_rename` doesn't support 4 part naming. Connect to the database first, and then use the system procedure.

---

If you ever need to know what an object's literal should be, you can use `QUOTENAME` to find it out as well. For example:

```sql
SELECT QUOTENAME(N'[avail_memory_mb]');
```

Which brings back the `nvarchar(258)` value `[[avail_memory_mb]]]`. So, if you really wanted, you could do something like:

```sql
DECLARE @ObjectPath nvarchar(1000) = CONCAT(QUOTENAME(N'dbo'),N'.',QUOTENAME(N'tbl_m_comp_sysboot_time'),'.',QUOTENAME(N'[avail_memory_mb]'));
EXEC sys.sp_rename @ObjectPath, N'avail_memory', N'COLUMN';
```